# How to bind multi-select-list to a property within a list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried the following but the AddFacultyDetailsViewModel is returned with empty FacultyConditionRow list

This is my viewModel

```
public class AddFacultyDetailsViewModel
{
    public AddFacultyDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new List<FacultyConditionRow>();
    }
    public SelectList ConditionsList { get; set; }
    public List<FacultyConditionRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

This is the type within the list

```
public class FacultyConditionRow
{
   public FacultyConditionRow()
   {
       SelectedConditionsExceptions = new List<int>();
   }
   public List<int> SelectedConditionsExceptions { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view that contains the multi-select-list

```
@model ViewModels.AddFacultyDetailsViewModel

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="input-group ">
        <select
          asp-for="@Model.Rows.ElementAt(i).SelectedConditionsExceptions"
          asp-items="@Model.ConditionsList">
        </select>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the AddFacultyDetailsViewModel is returned with empty FacultyConditionRow list

To make selected value(s) can be bound to `List<FacultyConditionRow> Rows` property of your viewmodel class automatically, please modify the `asp-for` attribute of select tag helper as below.

```
<form method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="input-group ">
            <select asp-for="@Model.Rows[i].SelectedConditionsExceptions"
                    asp-items="@Model.ConditionsList">
            </select>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Test Result

*Posted formdata*

[image]

*Debug result*

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer is helpful